# What would be the best way to showing nested comment(s)?

Tags: php, kohana

To implement this feature I had created a a column `replyTo` which relates to the `comment_id` in the same table. The original comments have this as `0`. The problem I face is what could be the best way to show them.

In my model, I have created a function `nested_comments()`  to get them and in my view I was doing like, this.

```
<? foreach( $comments as $comment ): ?>
....
          <? foreach( $comment->nested_comments() as $comm): ?>
```

But that is only fine if I have one level of nested comments. Actually, I wish if there was a way to do this in the view. I don't wish to create another view file and controller for this purpose alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function, Like below:

```
function getComments($comments){
      if(!is_array($comments)){
          return;
       }
     foreach($comments as $key => $value){
          // do what you want with comments
          getComments($nestedComments);
     }
}
```

it's not ready to use function, but you can work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with mptt modules, there are a few around:

https://github.com/spadefoot/kohana-orm-leap

https://github.com/rafi/orm-mptt

https://github.com/evopix/orm-mptt

I've been using third one but now its old and I suggest you to take a look at leap, it looks very promising.
And also take a look at http://kohana-modules.com/search?query=mptt

Comment: Note that its a Nested Sets, so you need to modify your table structure.